# TypeBuilder set type size

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I am trying to build a dynamic type and set its size, like `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=100)]` can. I have the following code:

```
Type structLayoutAttr = typeof(StructLayoutAttribute);
ConstructorInfo structLayoutAttrCtor = structLayoutAttr.GetConstructor(new[]{typeof(LayoutKind)});
object[] structLayoutAttrCtorArgs = new object[]{LayoutKind.Explicit};
FieldInfo[] structLayoutAttrSizeField = new FieldInfo[]{structLayoutAttr.GetField("Size")};
CustomAttributeBuilder cb = new CustomAttributeBuilder(structLayoutAttrCtor, structLayoutAttrCtorArgs, structLayoutAttrSizeField, new object[]{size});
tb.SetCustomAttribute(cb);
type = tb.CreateType();
```

However, this code fails at the last step - `CreateType` throws `TypeLoadException` about bad format. Is there a proper way to apply the attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`StructLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) attribute is a special attribute, it is handled by the compiler and compiled into a special metadata, thus you can't apply it with custom attribute building. Check the [`DefineType` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.modulebuilder.definetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there is one that takes the size of the type.